# Create list of objects from an object where the key is properCase using Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash.js

I'm trying to create a filtered list of objects where each object in the list has both a label and value property.

First I use `.pick` to select the key/value pairs I want from the initial object, then I iterate over the 'picked' properties and push the `key` into an object property called `label`, and push the `value` of the property into a property called `value`. I then return the `empty` array.

```
function formatToInput(obj, list) {
    var empty = []

    _.forIn(_.pick(obj, list), (val, key) => {
        empty.push({
            label: _.startCase(key),
            value: val
        });
    });

    return empty;
}

// use like so

var test = {blue: 10, green: 5, yellow: 3, pink: 1};
var filter = ['green', 'yellow'];

var results = formatToInput(test, filter)

console.log(results);

// [{label: Green, value: 5}, {label: Yellow, value: 3}]
```

I'm trying to avoid having to manually create an array and pushing objects into it, but I couldn't find a solution (in Lodash) that would allow me to do this.

Comment: Is there any chance to have values in `filter` which are not in `test`?

Answer (score 3):

The code looks like you're passing the processed data to autocomplete.

### Naming

- `formatToInput`: This gives no idea of what the function is doing.
- `empty`: Is it really empty at the end of `formatToInput`?
- `obj`, `list`: Confusing.
- `test`, `results`: Can be named better.

### Lodash

Do you really need a library for this functionality? The Same functionality can be done without Lodash or any other library. If Lodash is only used for this functionality, it can be removed.

### Missing Semi-colons

Although, a small thing [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/2025923) can lead to unexpected behavior. The usage of the semi-colon is not consistent. I'll recommend using [JSLint](http://jslint.com/)/[JSHint](http://jshint.com/).

### Alternative

I'll recommend the use of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and String methods to make the first character uppercase.

```js
const colorValueMap = {
  blue: 10,
  green: 5,
  yellow: 3,
  pink: 1
};
const colors = ['green', 'yellow'];

const result = colors.map(color => ({
  label: color[0].toUpperCase() + color.slice(1),
  value: colorValueMap[color]
}));
console.log(result);
```

---

Above solution assumes that the value from the filter array always exists in the object. If this is not the case, you can first `filter` the array and then use `map` on it.

```
colors.filter(color => colorValueMap.hasOwnProperty(color)).map(color => ({
    ...
});
```

Comment: Functionally this is a bit different, the original only copies over existing attributes from the filter. You create all attributes regardless, with `undefined` values when the original object does not have the attribute. Perhaps you could first filter, then map?

Comment: @konijn True. I've updated the answer. Thanks :)